# Incremeting a byte and comparing, is this behaviour defined?

Tags: c

Suppose that both `ab` and `cd` are declared to be of type `unsigned char*`. Is the behavior in the following code snippet well defined? My concern is the addition of `1` to `cd[k]` when `cd[k] = 255`, the expected behavior is that the comparison `ab[k] > cd[k] + 1` will then be equivalent with `b[k] > 256`? Not `b[k] > 0`? Is this correct?

```
if (ab[k] > cd[k] + 1)
{
    r = 1;
}
else if (cd[k] > ab[k] + 1)
{
    r = -1;
}
```

Comment: default integer promotions: C11 draft standard `6.3.1 Arithmetic operands
6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers, Section 2 [...] If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions.`

Comment: You can easily check for yourself. How a value is used does not affect how it is computed. So the question is, what does `j + 1` do if `j` is an `unsigned char` with value 255? And the answer is [give 256](http://codepad.org/Z9mQqwst).

Comment: Thanks, I already checked, but I am feeling frustrated, why would integer promotion play such a mind trick, my modular arithmetic education says that 255 + 1 = 0?

Comment: If integer promotion weren't at play, `unsigned char` would still not be required to be eight bits wide.

Comment: @cad I think it would. The standard mandates 255 as `UCHAR_MAX`.

Comment: @PSkocik: No. C11 draft standard, `5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>, Section 1 [...] Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.[...]`. Note the `or greater`.

Comment: @PSkocik I have to disagree in turn. From C11 standard draft N1570, §5.2.4.2.1.2: `The value UCHAR_MAX shall equal 2[^(CHAR_BIT − 1)].`, where CHAR_BIT is at least eight but possibly 100.

Comment: @cad Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @PSkocik: All these limits are minimum (maximum for negative) values. See the standard [(last sentence)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1p1)

Answer (score 4):

From the C11 standard draft N1570, §6.3.1.1.2:

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as
>   restricted by the width, for a bit-field), **the value is converted to
>   an** `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are
>   called the **integer promotions**.<sup>58)</sup> All other types are unchanged by the
>   integer promotions.
>   [...]
>   <sup>58)</sup> The integer promotions are [...] as part of the usual
>   arithmetic conversions, to certain argument expressions, to the
>   operands of the unary `+`, `-`, and `~` operators, and to both operands of
>   the shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.

In short, every expression with a type smaller than `int` or `unsigned int` is converted to `int` or to `unsigned int`, respectively.
An `int` has to be **at least 16 bits wide**, so definitely no wrap-around will occur and your expression will yield `256`.

Comment: *in short*, to make a `long` story `short`... +1